# How to set hAxis.viewWindow.max for a LineChart when the major axis is typeofday?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I need to draw a chart to show the evolution of data in real time in a day. I've been playing in [Google Charts Playground](https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart) to see how it would be visualized, but I haven't been able to set the hAxis.viewWindow.max option, in order to make the X axis be fixed.

Here is the code I've been using to test:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('timeofday', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S0');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S2');

  data.addRows([
    [[0,0,0,0],   1,       1,           0.5],
    [[1,0,0,0],   2,       0.5,         1],
    [[2,0,0,0],   4,       1,           0.5],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                  hAxis: {maxValue: [23,59,59,0], minValue:[0,0,0,0], viewWindow:{max: [23, 59, 59, 0]}}}
          );
    }
```

The documentation claims that hAxis.viewWindow.max receives numbers, but I haven't found a way to represent the "timeofday" type as a number.
​
Using that, the X axis goes from 0am to 2am, but I needed the axis to go until midnight.

I tried using "datetime" as the column type, with the same problem.

The sample below, using numbers, works the way I intended it to, drawing the line where my points are, but extending the grid until my max value:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S0');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S1');
  data.addColumn('number', 'S2');

  data.addRows([
    [0,   1,       1,           0.5],
    [1,   2,       0.5,         1],
    [2,   4,       1,           0.5],
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data, {curveType: "function",
                  width: 500, height: 400,
                  vAxis: {maxValue: 10},
                  hAxis: {maxValue: 23, minValue:0, viewWindow:{max: 23}}}
          );
}
```

​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

X axis will end up to your max value for it (or close in same cases - like this one). For example

in case of:

```
data.addRows([
    [[0,0,0,0],   1,       1,           0.5],
    [[1,0,0,0],   2,       0.5,         1],
  ]);
```

the x axis will end at **1:00**

in case of:

```
 data.addRows([
    [[0,0,0,0],   1,       1,           0.5],
    [[1,0,0,0],   2,       0.5,         1],
    [[23,59,59,0],   4,       1,           0.5],
  ]);
```

it will end at **23:59:59** showing **22:00** as the last x axis label.

This means that no matter the value your define as max in hAxis, the chart runs up to the max "timeofday" value you have in your dataRows (actually the last added row).

Comment: That contradicts the documentation, that claims that `"hAxis property that specifies the highest horizontal axis grid line. The actual grid line will be the greater of two values: the maxValue option value, or the highest data value, rounded up to the next higher grid mark."`

Even though, there is the hAxis.viewWindow.max parameter, that works for number data, but not for timeofday data. I've updated the question in order to consider that.

Comment: I know. So if you go to https://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart and keep the basic sample, you can make the hAxis to end to Z. It's not only for timeofday.

Comment: Well, I guess it's just not possible, then.